# New "On cbvl" notification on lock screen

Tags: notifications, lock-screens

I just noticed about an hour ago that on my lock screen, on the bottom left just above my phone icon, there is a new suspicious looking "on cbvl" notification.

There are 3 little notifications in the cluster. The first is the wifi icon with "sprint", which is usually there. The second is "Charging" which is normally there when I'm charging. The third is this new mystery line that has the silhouette-of-a-head icon (used for contacts) that says "On cbvl".

Does anyone know what this is? It is making me very nervous because I cant find anything on Google about it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

My pocket was busy. It went to:

Apps> Settings> Lock Screen> Owner Info

And checked the checkbox, and then closed everything out.

Nothing nefarious. My owner name is just apparently "cbvl", and my lock screen was telling me that.